# How to segue with a UITableViewController without navigation bar showing on other view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to segue from my `UITableViewController` to another `ViewController`, but I don't want the navigation bar to show on the other view controller (the one that where you press the button on it, it takes you back to the `UITableViewController`).

This is what I'm talking about...

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that on the next VC:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
  self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

You can also use a `Modal` or `Popover` segue depending on the design.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot! I would like it as well but I don't have enough rep.